# Why Django Rest_Framework Response() not setting cookies on my browser but works perfectly fine using postman?

Tags: python, django, angular, django-rest-framework, jwt

I don't understand this bug or issue. So, i am building an application using Django Framework as the server and Angular as the client side. And consider using JWT on the server side. At first, i was testing Log in api(server) using Postman, works fine when log in and creating cookies and token however. When testing using any browser, then i don't get to see the cookies being set. By the way i am using djangocorsheader and jwt packages. I'll leave my views.py and client side. Also, I'd research and saw a few answers on youtube and here but no luck. The only issue i could think of is either my browser or i need to set something on Django side. Please help, any help appreciate it.

Client Side (app-http, set up)

app-http.service.ts

```
import { throwError as observableThrowError, throwError } from 'rxjs';

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { LocalStorageService } from '../localStorage/local-storage.service';
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppHttpService {
    public hostUrl = environment.API_URL;

    constructor(
        public localStorageService: LocalStorageService, public httpClient: HttpClient,
        public router: Router) { }
    getHeader(headerOptions, qparams = {}, doNotSendAuthorizationParam: boolean) {
        let headerParams = {};
        console.log(this.localStorageService.getSessionId())
        if (doNotSendAuthorizationParam !== true && this.localStorageService.getSessionId()) {
            //send authorization param
            headerParams['jwt_token'] = this.localStorageService.getSessionId();
        }

        if (headerOptions) {
            headerParams = { ...headerParams, ...headerOptions }
        }

        let params: HttpParams = new HttpParams();
        for (let key in qparams) {
            params.set(key, qparams[key]);
        }
        let headers = new HttpHeaders(headerParams);
        console.log(headers)
        return headers;
    }

    get(url, params: any = {}, headerOptions: any = {}, doNotSendAuthorizationParam: boolean = false) {
        let httpOptions = this.getHeader(headerOptions, params, doNotSendAuthorizationParam);
        return this.httpClient.get<any>(this.hostUrl + url, { params: params, headers: httpOptions }).pipe(map(data => {
            if (data) {
                return data
            } else {
                return []
            }
        }), tap(),
            catchError(this.handleError)
        )
    }

    post(url, params: any = {}, headerOptions: any = {}, doNotSendAuthorizationParam: boolean = false) {
        let httpOptions = this.getHeader(headerOptions, params, doNotSendAuthorizationParam);
        console.log(this.hostUrl + url, params, { headers: httpOptions });
        
        return this.httpClient.post<any>(this.hostUrl + url, params, { headers: httpOptions }).pipe(map(data => {
            if (data) {
                return data
            } else {
                return []
            }
        }), tap(), catchError(this.handleError))
    }

    put(url, params: any = {}, headerOptions: any = {}, doNotSendAuthorizationParam: boolean = false) {
        let httpOptions = this.getHeader(headerOptions, params, doNotSendAuthorizationParam);
        return this.httpClient.put<any>(this.hostUrl + url, params, { headers: httpOptions }).pipe(map(data => {
            if (data) {
                return data
            } else {
                return []
            }
        }), tap(), catchError(this.handleError))
    }

    delete(url, headerOptions: any = {}, doNotSendAuthorizationParam: boolean = false) {
        let httpOptions = this.getHeader(headerOptions, null!, doNotSendAuthorizationParam);
        return this.httpClient.delete<any>(this.hostUrl + url, { headers: httpOptions })
            .pipe(map(data => {
                if (data) {
                    return data
                } else {
                    return []
                }
            }), tap(), catchError(this.handleError))
    }

    public handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
        // return an observable with a user-facing error message
        return throwError(error.error);
    };
}
```

localStorage.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import jwt_decoded from "jwt-decode"


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LocalStorageService {

  user: string = "user";

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // console.log(this.user);
  }

  clear() {
    localStorage.clear()
    console.log(this.user)
  }

  getUserInfo() {
    // let userJson = localStorage.getItem(this.user);
    // const userData = userJson !== null ? JSON.parse(userJson) : null;
    let userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(this.user) || 'null')
    if (userData) {

        let decoded = jwt_decoded(userData.token);
        userData['userId'] = decoded;
        // return userData;
    }
      return userData;
  }

  setUserData(userData:any) {
    return localStorage.setItem(this.user, JSON.stringify(userData));
  }

  getSessionId() {
    let userData = this.getUserInfo();
    if (userData && userData.token) {
      return userData.token;
    }
  }
}
```

Django

login views.py

```
# CONTRIB
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json
import jwt
import datetime
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password, check_password
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from uuid import uuid4

# Modules
from ..models import User
from ..serializers import UserSerializer

# HELPERS
from ..helpers.services.services import generate_random_password, reset_password_notify_user, forgot_password_notify_user
from ..helpers.server_responses.http_responses import SUCCESS, SUCCESS_CODE, SERVER_ERROR, UN_AUTHORIZED, FORBIDEN_ACCESS
from ..helpers.common.common import EMAIL_OWNER

from ..helpers.services.professional_services import PROFESSIONAL_SERVICES

# Create your views here.

# LOADING ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
load_dotenv()

# UNIQUE ID RANDOMNIZE
uid = uuid4()


@api_view(["PUT"])
def log_in(request):
    print("api.log_in()")

    REQUEST_BODY = json.loads(request.body)

    USER_OBJ = {
        'username': REQUEST_BODY['username'],
        'password': REQUEST_BODY['password'],
    }

    print(request.COOKIES) // prints an empty dictionary {} if testing via my browser but not using Postman, rather prints the actual cookie if using Postman.

    USER_MODEL = User.objects.filter(username=USER_OBJ["username"]).first()

    if USER_MODEL is not None:
        if check_password(USER_OBJ["password"], USER_MODEL.password):
            serializer = UserSerializer(User.objects.filter(
                username=USER_OBJ["username"]), many=True).data
            # request.session['user'] = uid.int
            # request.session.set_expiry(7500)

            payload = {
                'id': USER_MODEL.id,
                'exp': datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=30),
                'iat': datetime.datetime.utcnow()
            }

            token = jwt.encode(payload, 'secret',
                               algorithm='HS256')

            serializer[0]["token"] = token

            response = Response()
            response.set_cookie(key='jwt_token', value=token,
                                httponly=True, samesite='lax')
            response.data = {
                "message": "You Log In successfully!",
                'data': serializer[0],
                "status_code": SUCCESS_CODE["STANDARD"],
                "status": SUCCESS["STATUS"],
            }

            return response

            # return Response(
            #     {
            #         "message": "You Log In successfully!",
            #         'data': ,
            #         "status_code": SUCCESS_CODE["STANDARD"],
            #         "status": SUCCESS["STATUS"],
            #     }
            # )

        else:
            return Response(
                {
                    "message": "The password you entered does not match our record!",
                    "status_code": UN_AUTHORIZED["CODE"],
                    "status": UN_AUTHORIZED["STATUS"],
                }
            )
    else:
        return Response(
            {
                "message": f"Username {USER_OBJ['username']} does not exist!",
                "status_code": UN_AUTHORIZED["CODE"],
                "status": UN_AUTHORIZED["STATUS"],
            }
        )
```

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for server project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 4.1.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/
"""
import os
from pathlib import Path
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from corsheaders.defaults import default_headers

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# from porject root locate file .env
load_dotenv(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '.env'))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'api.apps.ApiConfig',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware"
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'server.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'server.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': os.environ["DB_ENGINE"],
        'NAME': os.environ["DB_NAME"],
        'USER': os.environ["DB_USER"],
        'PASSWORD': os.environ["DB_PASSWORD"],
        'HOST': os.environ["DB_HOST"],
        'PORT': os.environ["DB_PORT"],
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

# EMAIL CONFIG
EMAIL_BACKEND = "django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend"
EMAIL_HOST = os.environ["ENV_EMAIL_HOST"]
EMAIL_PORT = os.environ["ENV_EMAIL_PORT"]
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get("ENV_EMAIL")
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ["ENV_EMAIL_PASSWORD"]
EMAIL_USE_TLS = os.environ["ENV_EMAIL_TSL"]

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

# CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = list(default_headers) + [
#     "jwt_token",
# ]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

# CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
#     "http://localhost:8000",
#     "http://localhost:4200",
#     "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
# ]

# CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True # If this is used then `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS` will not have any effect
# CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

Comment: Does using `{withCredentials: true}`  option in your httpClient calls help?

Comment: @Igonato,, I just did and it does not work. In fact, i get an error of undefined and does not complete the call or fails.... this is weird!

Comment: @Igonato, I just noticed, if i open the developer tools on my browser and go to Network tab then i am able to see the cookies from both Response and Request headers... but not under Application > Cookies!?

Comment: Do you have a `cookie` header in your `httpOptions`? Otherwise, you shouldn't see it in the Request headers if you don't see in the Application > Cookies

Comment: Also, look for [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) header in the response headers. That's how cookies get set from the server. You won't be able to access it from js, but you should see it in the network dev tools tab

Comment: @Igonato... II wish there could be a way to show screenshots here.. But, on the developer tools under Network tab > api-call > Response headers - in here i am able to see Set-Cookie and Request header i am able to see cookie_name (which is jwt_token) as i defined in my httpOptions.... Does this mean it works fine? am i suppossed to see it under Application > Cookie? I do apologize for the many questions, i'm just a beginner learning Django and CORS and JWT

Comment: @Igonato. BUt then again, using postman i am able to retrieve the cookie name after setting the cookie with print(request.COOKIES) but when using Angular which is weird.

Comment: Yes. Sounds like you should to see it under Application > Cookie. Check that you didn't disable cookies for the page. If you're on Chrome, check that you didn't accidentally click "Only show cookies with an issue" checkbox. Try devtools in other browsers. If you get set-coockie header in the response, you should have it in the Application > Cookies tab

Comment: @Igonato Tried with Microsoft Edge browser and nope, under Application > Cookies > not shown but able to see it under Network tab..... Also, checked if i have disabled cookies by accident which i did not. I was able to create another option in httpOptions as 'authorization'  for token and only then i am able to access from django like so print(request.headers['authorization']). this is so weird i can't think what the issue is or the cause of this.